# Populate a struct from data in a std::vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++

I have the following struct defining data returned from a collection of HID device reports:

```
struct DevInfo {
    char unknown[0x40];
    string name;
    char unknown2[0x240];
};
```

It's currently incomplete, but that's irrelevant to my question.  Previously, I was populating an instance of this struct using `memcpy` to copy data from a char array, like so:

```
// get data from HID device
unsigned char *response = sendCommand(DEV_REPORT);

// Copy to struct
DevInfo *info;
memcpy(&info, &response[0], sizeof(response));

// Output name
cout << "Name: " << info->name << "\n";
```

This worked, except that I was apparently doing something that I shouldn't (returning a reference to a char array from a function).  So, after researching, I switched to a safer `std::vector<unsigned char>` approach, but now I can't use `memcpy` to populate the data in the struct.

Someone advised me to use `std::vector<DevInfo>` instead of `std::vector<unsigned char>`, but the problem with that is there are several different reports that can be retrieved from the HID device, so I need to be able to populate different structs using the same function (`sendCommand`).

What's an appropriate way to get the binary data from my `std::vector<unsigned char>` to my `DevInfo` struct?

Comment: What is the type of `string name`? (If it is `std::string` then any sort of bitwise copying is not going to work).

Comment: @Mankarse: yes, it's `std::string`, I guess that's the problem then?

Comment: You have two problems with your code: DevInfo is not standard layout, and you never make a `DevInfo` object (you just make an uninitialized pointer to `DevInfo`). I would suggest changing the design so that `sendCommand` returns a [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html), [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html), or a `unique_ptr` to a base class (that you can downcast appropriately).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing stopping you from using either `std::memcpy` or `std::copy` to populate an object from binary data stored in a `vector`, as long as it is a trivially-copyable standard-layout type:

```
DevInfo info;
std::vector<char> response = get_response();

assert(response.size() == sizeof info);
std::copy(response.begin(), response.end(), reinterpret_cast<char*>(&info));
std::memcpy(&info, &response[0], sizeof info); // C++11 allows response.data()
```

However, in your case it appears that you have a non-trivial data member (assuming that `string` refers to `std::string`), so you can't do either of these things.

Comment: I'm aware that in many cases, the optimiser will reduce `copy`/`memcpy` to this anyway, and doing it your way is probably preferable, but... - Isn't it also allowed to `reinterpret_cast<SomeType *>( vec.data() )`, at least if `SomeType` has `char` alignment or you use an aligned allocator?